# What makes this struct incomplete?

Tags: c, gcc, struct

`gcc` lovingly throws me this error:

`bst.c:33: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct BSTNode’`

What makes BSTnode incomplete?  Below are the struct definitions relevant to BSTnode.

```
struct BSTnode{

    struct BSTnode * left;
    struct BSTnode * right;

    struct hash minhash;
    struct hash maxhash;

    struct DHTid owner;
    int misses;
};
```

where we have:

```
struct hash{
    int hash;
};

struct DHTid
{
    int islocal;

    unsigned long addr;
    unsigned short port;
    struct DHTnode * node;
};
```

and currently:

```
struct DHTnode{
    int something;
};
```

EDIT: My actual code has the following structure:

```
struct DHTnode{...};
struct hash{...};
struct DHTid{...}; /*changed . to ; in pseudocode*/
struct BSTnode{...};
```

EDIT: user318466 pointed a missing semicolon, but there was still more wrong with it.

Comment: Needs semicolons after the hash and DHTNode struct definitions.

Comment: @Boojum: sorry that was a copy paste error :/.  it's actually in my code.

Comment: **Always** paste the original **complete program**. You see how much inconvenience this causes if you don't do it..

Comment: One more thing `struct hash` has a variable called `int hash;`. Compiler is throwing error for that. If I correct it there is no error. Is it like it in the actual code?

Comment: or possibly read the question thoroughly before you answer?

Comment: @Naveen I have had no problems with the `hash` struct yet.  it was the first piece that I wrote.

Comment: @Naveen: There's absolutely no problem with having a field named `hash` in a struct named `hash`. If your compiler complains about it, it must be a problem with your compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You declared type `struct BSTnode`. You are applying `sizeof` to type `struct BSTNode`. Note the difference in capitalization: **`n`** and **`N`**. `struct BSTNode` is, of course, a completely unknown to the compiler incomplete type, which is what it is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing `;` at the end of:

```
struct DHTid{...}.
```

it should be:

```
struct DHTid{...};
```

Comment: I presume you mean `DHTnode`?
unfortunately, it still gives me the same error. :/

Comment: I'm assuming he means DHTid, where you have left a dot, not a semicolon, after the structure. Note that if you take the time to say "My code actually looks like this", we'll take your word for it, problems and all.

Comment: Oh.  I didn't realize that he didn't read the rest of it.  I was under the impression that structure was a more abstract term in the English language than a photographic imprint.

Answer (score 0):

Your header files probably #define one of your identifiers to be something you don't want.

Comment: I have no `#define`s.  Also, before someone says I should paste the whole code, there are three files and some 500 lines.